# c# label is not being added to form when the method to create it is called

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm trying to create a label when a button is clicked. I think the problem is because I'm calling the method to create the button from another user control?

I know it's a mess.

User Control I want the label to be displayed on

```cs
namespace Test
{
    public partial class HomeTab : UserControl
    {
        //private string name;
        public Label nameLbl = new Label();// = new Label();

        public HomeTab()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public HomeTab(string name)
        {
            nameLbl.Name = "userIntro";
            nameLbl.Text = "awd, " + name;
            //nameLbl.Location = new Point(304, 376);
            nameLbl.AutoSize = true;
            nameLbl.Font = new Font("Calibri", 18);
            nameLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            nameLbl.Parent = panel2;
            nameLbl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

            nameLbl.Refresh();
        }
          
    }
}
```

User control with the button

```cs
namespace Button
{
    public partial class IntroTab : UserControl
    {
        public IntroTab()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // submit button
        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            string name = textBox2.Text;

            File.WriteAllText("MainSave.txt", name);
            string text = File.ReadLines("MainSave.txt").Skip(0).First();

            initializeData();

            HomeTab ht = new HomeTab("hello");

            this.Hide();
              
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In future, please try to provide a *minimal* example - a lot of the code here isn't really relevant to the question. (As an aside, I'd also strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions.) Also, please use the preview to check how your post will look before you submit it - the formatting was messed up because you'd used apostrophes instead of backticks for the code blocks. It's an easy mistake to make, but it's also easy to spot if you look at the preview. See  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more formatting help.

Comment: Finally, you said what you wanted to happen, but you didn't say what *actually* happened. I *suspect* a NullReferenceException is being thrown because `nameLbl` is null, but we can't tell from the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet - `nameLbl` shouldn't be null it is declared in the scope of the class `public Label nameLbl = new Label();`

Comment: Why do you have declare a new Form: `Form1 f = new Form1();`  and a new UserControl instance: `HomeTab ht = new HomeTab("hello");` in `submitButton_Click` and you do nothing with them? What was this supposed to do? Then, you have `IntroTab it = new IntroTab();` in `OnHandleCreated`. You do know that the handle could be recreated more than once? But you, apparently, do nothing with that, too. It appears you're creating instance of Forms/Controls inn the *hope* of reaching existing instances and *do something / make something appear*. Won't happen.

Comment: If you want to add a control to a container (like a form or user control), you need to pass it to the container's `Controls.Add()` method. See duplicate. In the code above, you create the `Label` object, but then never actually add it to the container.

Comment: @RandRandom: Yup, I hadn't seen that part. I'd assumed it was in the designer. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `HomeTab(string name)` constructor doesn't chain to the parameterless one, so `InitializeComponent` is never called.

I haven't looked at the rest of the code (there's rather a lot of it) but you *may* be able to just change the constructor like this:

```cs
public HomeTab(string name) : this()
{
    ...
}
```

That's required to set up anything else in the form. You *also* need to add the label to the form's controls, e.g. with `Controls.Add(nameLabel)`.

However, it's not clear why you're doing all of this manually anyway. It would make more sense to me to include label in the designer with all the properties you want, so your constructor would just need to be:

```cs
public HomeTab(string name) : this()
{
    nameLbl.Text = "awd, " + name;
}
```

Everything else would be handled by the designer.

Comment: Still does not display the label. The program runs and executes fine but no label.

Comment: @user90237864: See my edit - I hadn't spotted that the `nameLabel` field was handwritten rather than part of the designer. Given that it looks like you are *using* the designer (given the InitializeComponent call) you might as well use it fully.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are missing (additionally to JonSkeet's answer) is simply using the created instance of the label, you are only creating it but never actually put it somewhere in your user interface.

So what you are missing is

```
this.Controls.Add(nameLbl);
```

This assumes you want to put the instance `nameLbl` into the collection `Controls` of `this`.

If you call it in the `constructor` of `HomeTab` `this` will be the `HomeTab`, like so

```
public HomeTab(string name)
{
    //Label nameLbl = new Label();
    nameLbl.Name = "userIntro";
    nameLbl.Text = "awd, " + name;
    //nameLbl.Location = new Point(304, 376);
    nameLbl.AutoSize = true;
    nameLbl.Font = new Font("Calibri", 18);
    nameLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    nameLbl.Parent = panel2;
    nameLbl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

    nameLbl.Refresh();

    this.Controls.Add(nameLbl); //<-----
}
```

Notice you can ommit `this` I demonstrated it to clarify where it is going to be added, you can change `this` to any control the instace `nameLbl` should be added.

This error can be found in various places of your shared code eg.

```
HomeTab ht = new HomeTab("hello");
IntroTab it = new IntroTab();
```

Both those line only create an instance but you never put the instance into your user interface.

Comment: Please don't provide half an answer. If you believe that's Jon Skeet's answer is right, but there's more to it, then please include the full answer. The OP can only accept one answer and it should be complete.

Comment: ive tried Control.Add(nameLbl); also. still doesnt not seem to work

Comment: @Enigmativity - no, thanks

Comment: @user90237864 - as I already mentioned only doing `nameLbl` isn't enough, you are still missing to add `HomeTab ht = new HomeTab("hello");` - if you only did `nameLbl` you only added it to the instance of `HomeTab` but you didn't add `HomeTab` to anything - so basically all controls you manually create need to be added somewhere, and the whole chain of controls eg. `Form` is your root, if you create a `TabControl` you need to add it to the `Form`, if you create `TabItem` you need to add it to `TabControl`, if you create label you need to add it to `TabItem` and so on